# Formualting a logic in farmer astronaught

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, coq

There is this logic in a movie which I can't quite formalize (e.g. in Coq).

Some one wanted to launch a rocket on his farm, the FBI guys monitoring the site are talking to one another about why they are there. One guy said:

> Because if we are not here and he launches, we will look like as*s.

Then the other guy responded

> what if we are here and he launches?

answer:

> we'll still look like as*s.

It seems that the logic here is this:
Given:

```
A = we look foolish
B = he launches
C = we are not here.
```

We have

```
 B /\ C -> A    and
 B /\ ~C -> A
```

Furthermore, it seems that whether `C` (we are here) holds does not matter. The conclusion boils down to `B -> A`. (If he launches, we will look foolish).

Can we prove this reasoning?

I tried:

```
Theorem farmer: forall A B C:Prop, 
(B /\ C -> A) -> (B /\ ~C -> A) -> (B -> A).
Proof.
intros. tauto.
```

Then it's stuck. I tried adding the excluded middle, but `tauto` still can't prove it.

On the other hand, doing boolean algebra, we have:

```
(~B + ~C + A)(~B + C + A) = 
(~B + A)C + (~B + A)~C + (~B +A) =
~B + A.
```

i.e.

```
(B /\ C -> A) /\ (B /\ ~C -> A) = B -> A.
```

How can this be proved in Coq's logic, or did I derive it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you failed with Law of excluded middle, because it is sufficient to prove the proposition:

```
Axiom LEM: forall P:Prop, P \/ ~P.

Theorem farmer: forall A B C:Prop, 
(B /\ C -> A) -> (B /\ ~C -> A) -> (B -> A).
  intros.
  destruct (LEM C); tauto.
Qed.
```

Comment: I just tried tauto diectly as a premise and tauto didn't do it.

Comment: Axiom-free solution: prepend the propositional part with double negation `~~ ((B /\ C -> A) -> (B /\ ~C -> A) -> (B -> A))` and use `intros; tauto`. This works because of [Glivenko's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation#Propositional_logic): "If ϕ is a propositional formula, then ϕ is a classical tautology if and only if ¬¬ϕ is an intuitionistic tautology."

Answer (score 0):

Without decidability of your proposition, I'm not sure you can prove what you want: you still need to know if `C` is true or not. However your statement requires complex propositional equality, I advise you to rather state:

```
forall A B C:Prop, ((B /\ C) -> A) /\ ((B /\ ~C) -> A) -> (B -> A).
```

Answer (score 0):

The discussion is moot because if he doesn't launch the only thing that happens is plowing a feild cultivated 1000's of times... not nessarally foolish considering the ends to the means but the truly foolish thing in my opinion about your equation is that they don't help him launch because without the launch they are all still here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).